# Need a hint on how to solve this matrix equation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

\begin{equation}
AX+XA=B
\end{equation}

$A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ is available.

The furthest I've gotten is:
\begin{equation}
X+A^{-1}XA=A^{-1}B
\end{equation}
which doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a [Sylvester equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation).
Note that a unique solution will require that $A$ be non-singular and have no eigenvalue pairs of the form $\lambda$ and $-\lambda$. That Wikipedia page describes several well known solution methods that are implemented in standard mathematical packages.